# How to create dynamic url with logged in username in Angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript, dynamic-url

I have never done this before so that is why i have put this question here and need an explanation or an example blog that can tell me exactly how i can create a dynamic url like this `demo.com/username`. Currently my routes are working like this `demo.com/settings/emailsettings` but i need to implement the logic that it becomes `demo.com/username/settings/emailsettings`.

Note: The above urls are just for example and they are not real.

Comment: We cannot open any of those links.

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/router#route-parameters

Comment: @Mises in the explanation of my question i did say that the above written urls are not real and are only written so that people can get an idea of what i want to do

Comment: Sorry but i have no any simple project so i could show you how it works try to find some tutorial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your routes you need to define a param

```
{
  path: '/:username/settings/emailsettings',
  component: YourComponent
}
```

Then, when navigate by code you will pass the username to the route dynamically.

From component class:

```
this.navigate([user.username, 'settings', 'emailsettings'];
```

From component template

```
[routerLink]="[user.username, 'settings', 'emailsettings']"
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try below code:

```
let url='demo.com/settings/emailsettings';
let pos=url.indexOf('/')+1;
let userName='myUserName/';
let outputUrl=[this.url.slice(0,pos),userName,this.url.slice(pos)].join('');
```